# How to ban other threads from sending/posting messages

Tags: winapi

Or how to determine if a given message was posted/sent programmatically by another thread or simply another process?

By post and send I mean functions `PostMessage` and `SendMessage`

Comment: Better hope that you don't need any of those messages that Windows sends you. This is something of an XY problem. Why would you want to stop your process from receiving messages?

Comment: [`InSendMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-insendmessage) - can determinate case when message sent from another thread. but not when post.

Comment: Well, if by 'another thread' or 'another process', you mean one that you have created and/or coded, then you can put signatures in either the `wParam` or `lParam` parameters, which the receiving thread can check. If you're talking about processes over which you have no control, then … dunno!

Answer (score 1):

The Windows API does not keep track of the *originator* of a message. So the only way to know where a message comes from would be to directly hook the `(Post|Send)Message` functions in every running process.